# R-square excluding fixed effects using felm

Tags: r, stata

I am replicating work done in a published paper. It appears that the paper is reporting r-square values *excluding* the impact of fixed effects. The felm function from the lpm package in R returns an r-square value that *includes* the impact of fixed effects. The difference is similar to that between areg and xtreg in Stata as [described here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/areg-versus-xtreg-fe/). In other words, I can reproduce the published paper's results in Stata using xtreg, and I reproduce my results from R using areg. Is there a way to get felm in R to return an r-square value excluding the impact of fixed effects (i.e., similar to what xtreg reports in Stata)? If not, is there some other package in R that could accomplish this task? Thanks!

Comment: Usually, SO is for programming questions. This type of question is better suited for Cross Validated, [much like this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146431/what-does-it-mean-for-multiple-r-squaredproj-model-in-felm-package-lfe). Having said that, did you use `lfe`'s (not `lpm`)  `felm` yet? It gives you both the R2 with fixed effects and without. You can expand on these by manually calculating the R2, as they did in the link I included, as well.

Comment: This is helpful - particularly the tip about posting this sort of question to Cross Validated instead of SO. So thanks for explaining my mistake instead of simply downvoting the question. I had actually found the CV post you reference, but the solution proposed there is to manually calculate the version of the R-square I am looking for, which I am hoping to avoid. I will poke around some more specifically on Cross Validates and post there if I can’t find a solution.